# Flutter: Put a response data into a dropdown

Tags: flutter, dart

i have an app and i want to put a data that i received from a json (i have received before putting in the dropdown, so dont need to use a future) in a dropdown but i cant make it work.

Here is a function that i run at the start and receive the data from the  json:

```
Future loadEmployees() async {
    Response response;
    Dio dio = new Dio();
    String url = 'http://192.168.15.5:8090/api/employees';
    response = await dio.post(url);

    EmployeessList employeesList =
        EmployeesList.fromJson(response.data);
  
  }
```

So the data is stored at employeesList, but how can I show this on dropdown items?

Maybe using a for to run all the employees and send to a list?
I really dont know, ive been trying for some days and still cant do it.

Here is my PODO object class:

```
class EmployeesList {
  final List<Employees> employees;

  EmployeesList({
    this.employees,
  });

  factory EmployeesList.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson) {
    List<Employees> employees= new List<Employees>();
    employees= parsedJson.map((i) => Employees.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return new EmployeesList(
      Employees: employees,
    );
  }
}

class Employees{
  final int code;
  final String name;

  Employees({this.code, this.name});

  factory Employees.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new Employees(code: json['Codigo'], name: json['Nome']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map a list of entities. For example:

```dart
return DropdownButton<Employee>(
  items: employeesList.map((employee) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<Employee>(
      value: employee,
      child: Text(employee.name),
    );
  }).toList(),
);
```